# split content of column into lines in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe df:

```
+------+----------+--------------------+
|SiteID| LastRecID|        Col_to_split|
+------+----------+--------------------+
|     2|1056962584|[214, 207, 206, 205]|
|     2|1056967423|          [213, 208]|
|     2|1056870114|     [213, 202, 199]|
|     2|1056876861|[203, 213, 212, 1...|
```

I want to split the column into lines like this:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|     RecID|        index|        Value|
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|1056962584|            0|          214|
|1056962584|            1|          207|
|1056962584|            2|          206|
|1056962584|            3|          205|
|1056967423|            0|          213|
|1056967423|            1|          208|
|1056870114|            0|          213|
|1056870114|            1|          202|
|1056870114|            2|          199|
|1056876861|            0|          203|
|1056876861|            1|          213|
|1056876861|            2|          212|
|1056876861|            3|          1..|
|1056876861|       etc...|       etc...|
```

Value contains the value from the list.
Index contains the index of the value in the list.

How can I do that using PySpark ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Spark 2.1.0, you can use `posexplode` which *unnest* array column and output the index for each element as well, (used data from @Herve):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.select(
    F.col("LastRecID").alias("RecID"), 
    F.posexplode(F.col("coltosplit")).alias("index", "value")
).show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|RecID|index|value|
+-----+-----+-----+
|10526|    0|  214|
|10526|    1|  207|
|10526|    2|  206|
|10526|    3|  205|
|10896|    0|  213|
|10896|    1|  208|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

I quickly tried with Spark 2.0
You can change the query a little bit if you want to order differently.

```
d = [{'SiteID': '2', 'LastRecId': 10526, 'coltosplit': [214,207,206,205]}, {'SiteID': '2', 'LastRecId': 10896, 'coltosplit': [213,208]}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)

+---------+------+--------------------+
|LastRecId|SiteID|          coltosplit|
+---------+------+--------------------+
|    10526|     2|[214, 207, 206, 205]|
|    10896|     2|          [213, 208]|
+---------+------+--------------------+

query = """
select LastRecId as RecID, 
(row_number() over (partition by LastRecId order by 1)) - 1 as index, 
t as Value 
from test 
LATERAL VIEW explode(coltosplit) test AS t
"""
df.createTempView("test")
spark.sql(query).show()

+-----+-----+-----+
|RecID|index|Value|
+-----+-----+-----+
|10896|    0|  213|
|10896|    1|  208|
|10526|    0|  214|
|10526|    1|  207|
|10526|    2|  206|
|10526|    3|  205|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

So basically I just explode the list into a new column. And apply row number on this column.

Hope this helps